# Mvc apicontroller , how can i set unlimited length for maxJsonLength when i receive the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am  new to mvc and ran into an issue wile creating a controller api where it will be able to accept files in the httpRequest. It works fine for small files, but when the size of the file exceeds 4MB, it fails with "Internal server error", the request does not even hit my controller api.

I did see some posts where it has mentioned to use JavascripSerializer in a controller.
(Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config? 9)

But i am not sure how to use this when accepting a request with larger files.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> But i am not sure how to use this when accepting a request with larger files.

In your web.config you could increase the maximum size of the request:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Set the maximum request size to 1GB (the value is in KB here) -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

and if you are running in IIS 7 integrated pipeline mode you also need to set the `<requestLimits>` to the same value:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <!-- Set the maximum request size to 1GB (the value is in Bytes here) -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It works great!!. Thank you. But i would now have to deal with timeout issues.

Comment: Can we wrap the IIS 7 setting inside `<location path="controller/action">` ?

Comment: @user2433166 - you can set SqlCommand.Timeout = 0 for infinite.

Comment: @user2433166, you could also increase the `executionTimeout` property on the [`<httpRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx) element.